# Eclipse Debugging Android doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

HI all. I have a problem with Eclipse, debugging an android application: all breakpoints I place doesn't work ( the applications doesn't stop. They are skipped as not placed ). There's a way to make them work?

I have Win7, JDK 6u23 64bit, Eclipse 3.6 64bit, all breakpoints are enabled ( skip isn't selected ).

Thanks in advance for the answers :)

Comment: This is a very old question, but I just encountered the same problem. Two points to notice: 1) the ADT did *not* add android:debuggable=true to my manifest, I had to do it manually (31 Oct, 2013). And, 2) When I selected Window/Open perspective/Debugging, I notice a button the tool bar with tooltip "skip all breakpoints". Some it had been pushed. I clicked again and suddenly my breakpoints, which had all been marked as disabled, became enabled. Hope that helps someone in future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Does the thread list show up in the Debug perspective when you start the app?  If not, then Eclipse's debugger is not property attached to the phone/emulator.

Make sure you have `android:debuggable=true` in the [Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).  The latest version of the Eclipse ADT plugin should do this for you, but I've seen a few cases where it didn't work as I expected.

Comment: the manifest is ok, but you centered the problem: there's nothing in the tab "Debug" in the top left side of the debug view... how can I fix this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to go to the DDMS perspective and make sure your application (and device) is listed in the devices window and ensure that it is marked for debugging.

Comment: if I click on the process from DDMS perspective, and then on the debug Icon, I can finally debug!! ....unfortunately I incurred in an ANR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626103/debugging-widget-causes-anr thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Never had to use it, but on the Sony Ericsson phone we have at work the android:debuggable="true" tag needs to be in the manifest under the application tag. If left out all breakpoints are completely ignored...

Answer (score 4):

old question, but i've never found my answer anywhere else.  Mawg's comment to OP held some clues to my answer.

for me, "skip all breakpoints" was enabled by default (windows7 64bit, adt pluggin 2.22).

i had to go into the Breakpoints tab in the debug perspective to find this.  i dont' think it's shown in DDMS.  skipping breakpoints is separate from the checkmarks, which, i believe, is the same as "enabling" a breakpoint.  i'm not sure why there is a distinction.

i'd post a pic of a skipped breakpoint but i don't have 10 rep yet.
it's the blue circle, but with a "\" through it.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Eclipse and my device solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved a similar problem today.

Turns out I have disabled an Eclipse option on which the debug window is automatically shown after starting debug (that was annoying to me).

I have to manually focus the Eclipse debug window once in a session (while debugging) in order for the debug buttons (play/pause/etc) to become active. That was automatically done before.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse Luna with ATD plugin. When I tried to add `android:debuggable="true"` in `<Application>` of my App's Manifest.xml,  I got a compile error `Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assigned one.`

Finally, I found how to activate breakpoints, I should just press the **Debug** button (the ’bug‘ icon).