# Android debug not working: not stopping at breakpoints, not adding variables

Tags: java, android, debugging

Here is my problem: [image]

I simply want to see if `my_list` contains the string it got from `letters`. At the bottom of the code I use a toast method, and it shows that I have correctly added the string to `my_list`. But for some reason when I try debugging the program it doesn't add `my_list` or `letters` to the variables section. The variable section is empty. And as you can see, I have put tons of breakpoints in the code but the program just runs with breaking.

I have been trying to debug this application straight from my phone.
I have tried cleaning the project, restarting eclipse, building, changing code but the debugger just won't work.

Am I doing something wrong? Anybody know why these variables (`my_list` and `letters`) are not added to the variables perspective?

Please let me know if I need to provide more code or information.

Comment: I am using eclipse with java

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617062/eclipse-debugging-android-doesnt-work

Comment: thanks but my eclipse won't let me add android:debuggable=true. an error shows: Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one

Comment: figured out the solution. debugger was set to skip breakpoints. so i changed that setting. thanks though for your help

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem:

The debugger was set to "skip all breakpoints" for some reason. So once I changed that setting everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You have disabled breackpoins.
breakpoints icon should look like this. enable it.

[image]